# Remove &nbsp; generated by wp_dropdown_pages function

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been using this code on a WordPress development site.

```
    <?php $args = array(

    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'include'              => array (116, 214, 163, 165, 173, 175, 177),
    'show_option_none' => 'More Pages'

    ); ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="page-list">

        <?php wp_dropdown_pages ($args); ?>

    </div>
```

This outputs a dropdown list of a parent page and it's child pages as below.

But the problem is as you can see there is a space in the left side if each child items.

[image]

When I see on inspect element there are non-breaking spaces being generated by PHP. How can I remove these spaces?

```
<select name="page_id" id="page_id">
<option value="">More Pages</option>
<option class="level-0" value="116">Underfloor Heating</option>
<option class="level-1" value="214">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Underfloor Heating Cost</option>
<option class="level-1" value="163">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;What makes us different</option>
<option class="level-1" value="165">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;System Components</option>
<option class="level-1" value="173">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Floor Construction</option>
<option class="level-1" value="175">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Integration</option>
<option class="level-1" value="177">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;FAQs</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this code to your theme's functions.php to filter the results:

```
function remove_dropdown_spaces($output){
    $output = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $output);
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_pages', 'remove_dropdown_spaces' );
```

Note that if this isn't catching the spaces, try changing `'&nbsp;'` to an actual space, `' '`

Comment: Thanks I tried both solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you try changing the filter call to `add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_pages', 'remove_dropdown_spaces', 10, 3 ); `

Comment: I did that but the spaces are still there. Also did some hard refreshers but still the same.

Comment: I changed `$nbsp;` to `&nbsp;` and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @sparkinglabs ug sorry, that was a typo in my part I didn't notice.